# Mocha: tests cannot find module

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, es6-modules

I have a very simple unit test that starts in these lines:

```
import {SOUTH_EVENTS_ENUM, SouthEventsManager} from "@app/common/south_events_manager";
import {expect} from "chai";
import config from "config";
const {KafkaSouth} = require('@app/kafka_conn/kafka_south');
const sinon = require("sinon");

declare const Tester: any;

describe('SouthEventsManager', function()  {
    const kafkaSouthStub = sinon.createStubInstance(KafkaSouth);
    const southEventsManager = new SouthEventsManager(kafkaSouthStub);
```

As you can see, the module SouthEventsManager is imported in the test file.

I run Mocha with the following runner:
[image]

However, I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module '@app/common/south_events_manager' Require
> stack:
>
> - C:\HQNorth\North\test\common\south_events_manager.ts

As you can understand, the module SouthEventsManager cannot be found.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have configured path aliases in your `tsconfig.*.json` file. Mocha does not know it, it assumes it is some module (NodeJS one, relative file, or just 3rd party package). You need to tell it. You need to install package `tsconfig-paths` and change your Mocha running script to:

`mocha -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register "test/**/*.ts"`